# Accessing MySQL COUNT(*) result object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

When I run a query like,

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE item IN (1,2) GROUP BY item;
```

I get back an normal array with the objects returned, but I can't access the `COUNT(*)` value with a normal operation such as

```
result[0].COUNT(*)
```

as I would normally do `result[0].item`

How am I supposed to access this item? I tried to search for it around, but I only found solutions for PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name your aggregate column in your query

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) as [count] FROM table WHERE item IN (1,2) GROUP BY item;
```

and access it as a column

```
result[0].count
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE item IN (1,2) GROUP BY item;
```

Then in your javascript you can do: `result[0].count`

Answer (score 2):

If it's a naming issue, then rename the column like this

```
count(*) as count
```

then access it as before with `result[0].count`